# Size of incoming freshmen class

Tags: data.gov, collegescorecard

I'm looking for the size of the freshmen class of each college/year. I thought at first that I could use the `D100_4` field, but then realized that this actually represents the size of the freshmen class 6 years earlier. Am I correct in thinking that the data I'm looking for is not currently included in the raw data? If so, is there a reason for that? Do colleges not report the size of their freshmen class each year?

Answer (score 2):

I received an answer to my question by sending an inquiry to `scorecarddata@rti.org`.

The asked-for data is indeed not included in the Scorecard data set, but it released by IPEDS. I found what I was looking for in the "Fall enrollment" data at https://nces.ed.gov/ipeds/datacenter.